# Openerp product and supplier access rights issues

Tags: product, openerp-7

I am new to Openerp.  I am customizing it as per the requirements.  I have the following issues:

- **Issue 1:** I have introduces new statuses for products.  'Pending', 'Confirmed', 'Canceled'.  The issue now is, only 'Purchase manager' should be able to edit the confirmed products.  Regular users shall be able to edit only 'Pending products'.
- **Issue 2:** Admin User only can confirm the products.  I have implemented this.  But I need to do some validation.  Before confirming the product, 'Supplier' and 'Unit price' is mandatory. If not added, then need to display warning message.

I am trying to do these through customization (access rights, etc.).  But no luck.

**Edit1:**

```
from osv import fields, osv
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    _columns =  {
        'stage': fields.selection([
            ('pending', 'Pending'),
            ('confirmed', 'Confirmed'),
            ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
        ], 'Status', select=True, track_visibility='onchange', help='Product Workflow Stages')
    }

    _defaults = {
        'type' : 'consu',
        'stage': 'pending',
    }

    purchase_order()
```

**Customization through UI:**

[image]

Any help can save my days of work.

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1:

I assume that for now everyone can edit product in any state. To narrow privileges for normal users try record rules: Settings -> Security -> Record rules. There add one rule, something like: ['state','=','pending'], object Product, check "Apply for Write". Then go Settings -> Groups, go into the group of normal user and add this record rule in "Rules" tab. Maybe this will work.

Issue 2:

From what I understood, you want to make fields "Supplier" and "Unit price" obligatory when creating the product. In order to do that, in your XML, in those fields you have to add something like:

```
... attrs="{'required':True}"
```

Comment: posting your code would help a lot in solving problems you have

Comment: Thanks a lot.  But I did most of my work through customization.  I will try your above solutions now and I will post my code tomorrow as soon as I reach to work.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution for **issue 1:** I tried to put `[('stage','=', 'confirmed')]` in domain filter of the rule and I selected only 'Apply for read'.  But it did not work.  Also for **issue 2**, I want to make those fields mandatory when Admin going to confirm only. While creating the product those are not mandatory.  Please let me know if I am missing some thing.  Again thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you post code in which you are modifying product.product? it would help a lot. Issue 2: Ok so i misunderstood, you want to make those fields from obligatory to mandatory, right? In orded to do that, in your view (inheriting product view) you have to add to those fields something like that: `attrs = '{'required': [('stage','not in', and here you put a list of stages in which it should be mandatory}'

Comment: Regarding issue 1: if this thing with record rule did not work, try one more little thing - go into Settings -> Groups and open normal user group. Now in tab "Access rights" find object "Product" and uncheck it in field "Write access". Now test it with this record rule still active.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply and sorry for my late response.  I have attached the code and screenshot of what I did through customization.  Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: issue1: your solution will not work (did not work for me).  Because if we remove in **access rights** then it will be the top priority, then user normal cannot edit the product at any stage.  I want it to be editable when it is in pending stage.

Comment: Huh i think i finally got an answer after few additional tests:) Try that: create another record rule for product.product, leave checked only "Apply for Read", in rule definition type : [(1,'=',1)] and in groups add that normal user group. Next, go into that previously made rule and in rule definition write: [('stage','not in',['confirmed'])], leave checked everything beside "Apply for Read" and make sure that this rule is also assigned to the normal user group. Let me know if it works:)

Comment: I tried your recent solution.  But, it did not work.  I think I am doing some thing wrong.  I will try to apply the same for purchase orders status.  Because PO will be having default states.  Where as in product module I introduced the stages.  I will update you once I try with Purchase order object.  Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: Im sorry to hear that, ive run tests on task staging and it worked for me. Please let me know if you find something.